# Confusion about returning correct node

Tags: linked-list

I'm trying to understand the solution to [this LC problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/), which can be written like this:

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, list1: Optional[ListNode], list2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        dummy = ListNode()
        tail = dummy

        while list1 and list2:
            if list1.val > list2.val:
                tail.next = list2
                list2 = list2.next
            else:
                tail.next = list1
                list1 = list1.next
            tail = tail.next
        
        if list1:
            tail.next = list1
        elif list2:
            tail.next = list2

        return dummy.next
```

My confusion doesn't lie in the logic of the solution itself but rather the last line of code. Here's what I understand: 'dummy' is a ListNode object whose val attribute is '0' and next is 'None'. 'tail' is set equal to dummy which means it copies its attributes. Throughout the rest of the function, tail.next is repeatedly modified, whereas dummy.next isn't.

So, why does dummy.next return the head of the linkedlist?

Thanks

I tried understanding this problem for like 30 mins. I was expecting to understand it by now. What actually resulted is me feeling like a total idiot.

Answer (score 0):

You started with setting `tail` to `dummy`, and each addition into the list you added to `tail.next` and then moved the `tail` to `tail.next`. So at the end of the loop the list might be, for example:

> 0 -> 1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 10

because when you created `dummy = ListNode()` the default value was set to 0.
So when you want to get the proper linked list, you return `dummy.next` which would be:

> 1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 10